# Maintain scroll position on post back is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have given `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` on the @Page tag but its not working.

I am not using any update panel on the page.My .NET framework is 4.0 but still on postback its not working.

Please can anybody help me for the same?

Thank you.

Comment: checkout this http://gnidesign.blogspot.com.co/2011/06/how-to-maintain-page-scroll-on-postback.html - "Here is the fix. Place it between you pages <head> tags:

<script type="text/javascript">
       window.scrollTo = function () { }
</script>"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
            }
        }
```

Working fine in my page.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below:

I think you can add one hidden field in your page and on page load, using JavaScript we can get the position on that hidden field and set the page position based on that

See below:

```
    <div id="dvMain">

     <input type="hidden" id="hidden_place" name="hidden_place" />

    </div>


   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var maindiv = document.getElementById("dvMain");
        var hiddenposition = document.getElementById("hidden_place");
        var position = parseInt('<%=Request.Form["hidden_place"] %>');
        if (isNaN(position)) {
            position = 0;
        }
        maindiv.scrollTop = position;
        maindiv.onscroll = function () {
            hiddenposition.value = maindiv.scrollTop;
        };
    };
    </script>
```